# Is there a OS X Spotlight equivalent for *nix?

Tags: unix, search

I'm used to using Spotlight on OSX.

Is there anything equivalent for a generic *nix terminal?
I'm aware of GNU Find, but it's slow!

Is there a fast indexed search-in-files program?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [`locate(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/locate).  A cron job rebuilds the index (nightly, I believe, but I'm not sure of the frequency) with the `updatedb` command.  You shouldn't need to run that yourself, but you can if you recently added a lot of files and want the index to be up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which UNIX flavor you are using (Solaris, *BSD, Linux) and if you have that tool  installed. Try `locate`. To update its database run `updatedb` as root.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Spotlight can search for specific words in the content of files, `locate` cannot.

See [Using an index to make grep faster?](https://superuser.com/questions/320773/using-an-index-to-make-grep-faster/320839#320839) if you need to find files whose contents (not their file-names) contain specific words.